# JMeter (Ramp-up Period)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I need 5 times per second send (open, read, write).
I have question. I need to make:

- **Number of Thread User** - 5
- **Ramp-up period (seconds)** - 0.5 or 0,5 or something else?
  I made this one, its right?:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VldLV.png)

Comment: If you need it to send 5 times per second you need the period to be 0.2 between each time it sends

Comment: i need change 0.5 to 0.2 right?

Comment: Yes for it to work 5 times per second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 5 users will give you 5 requests per second only if response time will be exactly 1 second. If response time will be 2 seconds - you will get 2.5 requests per second. If response time will be 0.5 seconds - you will get 10 requests per second
2. Ramp-up period only controls the arrival rate of users

My expectation is that you need to go for [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) which allows specifying the desired number of requests per minute so if you configure it to 300 requests per minute it will try to keep throughput at this rate which will give you your desired 5 requests per second.

Also be aware that the Constant Throughput Timer can only **pause** the threads, if the current number will not be sufficient to get 5 requests per second throughput - it won't be able to kick off any extra threads. If this is also something you're looking for - consider [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination.